# countdown-timer increasing zero javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown-timer and i'm using the following code

```
if(hour < 10){ hour = "0"+hour;}
if(min < 10){ min= "0"+min;}
if(sec < 10){ sec= "0"+sec;}
```

the problems is when the min or hour reaches 0 like **11:00:50** it constantly add zero in it like this **11:0000000:45** instead of this **11:00:45** is there any way i can fix this problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing without more context and code surrounding this.

Comment: `if(hour < 10){ hour = "0"+hour; hour = hour.substring(0, 2) }`

Comment: i think someone posted a correct code but delete it this is the code 
 if(hour.toString().length < 2 && hour < 10){ hour = "0"+hour;} thats why i cant accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pad a number to two digits, I usually write a small *addZ* function like:

```
function addZ(n) {
  return (n<10? '0' : '') + +n;
}
```

and you can format your time like:

```
var formattedTime = addZ(hour) + ':' + addZ(min) + ':' + addZ(sec);
```

or even

```
var formattedTime = [addZ(hour), addZ(min), addZ(sec)].join(':');
```

It can be included in the main function and be called *z* or something similarly short.